# Can the only administrator account password be reset on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, passwords, user-accounts, administrator

I have setup a machine for a relative that have children, I made myself an account on the computer which is the only administrator account.

I have forgotten the password that I had setup the administrator account on the machine.
I did not create a recovery disk on setup nor did I associate any MS account with my user account.

Is there any way to reset the password on this account? Or make another administrator account?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I have found that works is to use a live cd ( I used ubuntu ) and physical access to the computer

Boot into the computer with a live cd or dvd
find Windows System 32 directory, renamed utilman.exe to utilman.old
copy cmd.com to utilman.exe 
Reboot the computer into Windows
At the Windows log in prompt I hit the “Windows”+”U” key and open pops a system level command prompt. From here you can type any windows command

At the command prompt type

***Net user John 123 /add***

This will add user named John with a password 123

Then type

***net localgroup administrators "John" /add***

This will give you admin privilege

Then reboot and try the new administrator account you could also change the old password that you forgot now

Comment: Cmd.exe is the correct program

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution to the problem following a page on About.com

http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows-8/a/reset-password-windows-8.htm

This is similar to user221429's suggestion however I think its more precise.

Using a recovery disk, I as able to boot into the command prompt, there I moved utilman.exe and replaced it with cmd.exe.

Rather than creating a new user though, I simply typed in...

```
net user [username] [password]
```

This command is able to reset the password of any given account.
You can also list all accounts by using `net user`